# drupal visit counter

Tags: drupal, visitor-statistic

I am new to drupal. i am making site in which requirement to implement counter as like provided by feedgit.com

this site provide widget to install. i have implemented on blog http://sonuit.blogspot.com/.

I want this in drupal.

please suggest for it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For this you should probably create a new Block and embed the widget code into that. The tricky bit is that you will need to create a new input format that doesn't filter out embedded JavaScript.

For that go to Admin / Site configuration / Input formats, create a title such as "allow javascript"

Now create a new block as usual and Choose your new input format. Then you should be able to paste in the widget code and have it appear on the page. Use the block settings to control where to put the block.

Comment: Remember, though, that such an "allow javascript" input format should never be allowed to be used by editors you don't fully trust. Allowing anyone to post javascript will open up severe XSS security holes. Configure the input format in a way that it can only ever be used by trusted users/roles.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use also ExtraWatch counter and live stats which is for drupal and has various features you'd like